# WCF service endpoint configuration doesn't like the binding attribute

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-endpoint

In my web.config file I have the following service defined:

```
<services>
  <service name="ShareYourWage.Service.WageService" behaviorConfiguration ="metadataBehavior">
    <endpoint>
      binding="basicHttpBinding"
      contract="ShareYourWage.Service.IWageService">
    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
```

Yet, when I debug the service, the test client throws the following error:

```
Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata.
```

and digging into the specific error points to the endpoint section shows the following error:

```
The configuration section cannot contain a CDATA or text element.
```

I've Googled this error and the MSDN site and have used their examples and still have this problem. A 2nd pair of eyes would be big help, thanks!

Comment: Not sure, but I think metadata is exposed by enabled IMetadataExchange contract. http://wcftutorial.net/metadata-exchange-endpoint.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You accidentally closed your `endpoint` tag before the `binding` and `contract` attributes.

Remove the '>' at the end of `<endpoint>`.

You want it to be like this:

```
<endpoint
  binding="basicHttpBinding"
  contract="ShareYourWage.Service.IWageService">
</endpoint>
```

If you're using Visual Studio or some other XML-aware text editor to modify the config files, the syntax highlighting can be helpful for spotting these kinds of problems.